# Why is the time from vernal and autumnal equinox different than from the autumnal to the vernal one?

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy

In my lecture the professor stated that the time from vernal to autumnal equinox is about 186 days , while that from autumnal to vernal equinox is about 179 days.
I was wondering why are these time intervals different? I would expect them to be equal, as I think the paths are symmetrical parts of the elliptical orbit of the earth

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> as I think the paths are symmetrical parts of the elliptical orbit of the earth

No, they are not symmetrical in the way you think.

Perihelion and aphelion are separated by exactly $180°$
(by definition of an ellipse).
Also vernal and autumnal equinox are separated by exactly $180°$
(by definition of the equinox line as the intersection of the
ecliptical plane with the equatorial plane).
But the angle between perihelion and vernal equinox is nothing special.
It just happens to be around $77°$.

Using all these we can draw the elliptical orbit of the earth.

[image]

We see, the winter path (from autumnal to vernal equinox)
is on average closer to the sun
than the summer path (from vernal to autumnal equinox).
Because of [Kepler's second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Second_law) smaller radius means higher speed.
And hence the winter half year is shorter than the summer half year.

Comment: I see, and of course first of all one notices that the area on the left of the equinoxial line is less that that to the right, because the sun is at a focus and not at the center of the ellipse

Comment: I believed the equinoxial line was perpendicular to the line joining the foci, but even without knowing this, one can realize that the areas are not the same by the previous comment I guess and knowing that the equinoxial line is obviously not equal to the the line joining the foci

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

1. The earth's orbit is an ellipse; the sun is located at a focus of the ellipse, not at the centre of the ellipse
2. The earth reaches perihelion in early January;
3. The earth reaches the winter solstice around Dec 21, so very near perihelion point
4. The vector from the sun to the earth sweeps out equal areas in equal time;

Now consider this crude diagram that grossly exaggerates the eccentricity of the earth's orbit (Seen from below, so the earth travels clockwise; Sorry about that):

Points 2 and 3 mean that the earth reaches perihelion at the left-most point of the ellipse, and the earth's axial tilt is almost exactly to the left.

Lastly, consider the area inside the ellipse to the LEFT of the line joining the equinoxes in comparison to the area inside the ellipse to the right of that line, and apply Point #4

[image]

Comment: Where is winter solstice?. How do we know that the equinoxes and the sun are aligned or at  that the line connecting the equinoxes is to the left of the sun?